# zeromq pattern: pub/sub with guaranteed delivery

Tags: zeromq

I'd like to fan out messages and be sure that any connected socket has received them, if present.

So is there a pattern to achieve the following:

- PUB socket shall block on watermark if there is one or more SUB connected, i.e. all of the SUB sockets have received the message.
- PUB socket shall drop on watermark if there is no SUB connected.

I use [nzmqt](https://github.com/jonnydee/nzmqt) within Qt5 on OSX/Linux, if this is helpful or the mentioned problem could be solved in this special case.

Comment: rabbitmq does have an 0mq adapter for such cases.

Comment: What you want to achieve is in general not recommended since a single slow subscriber or one unable to receive messages would block the whole thing, right? Or how do you mean it?

Comment: Right, that's what I mean. If as a consequence my process blocks on a slow or busy subscriber, I'd be okay with that. For example, ZeroMQ's PUSH socket is blocking, too, and that's intended. In fact, I'd like to make sure that no message is lost. Currently I'm thinking of implementing some kind of handshake-pattern to achieve that, but this adds a lot of complexity compared to what I have now and what I want.

Comment: Anybody have progress or an update on the answer to this?