# How to avoid dropping messages zeromq pub sub

Tags: c++, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I have seen several questions about this, but none have answers I found satisfactory. This question, [zeromq pattern: pub/sub with guaranteed delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059193/zeromq-pattern-pub-sub-with-guaranteed-delivery) in particular is similar, though I am open to using any other zeromq mechanism to achieve the same effect.

My question is, is there any way to send messages in a fan-out pattern like publisher-subscriber in ZeroMQ with the assurance that the messages will be delivered? It seems as though a Dealer with zero-copy could do this okay, but it would be much messier than pub-sub. Is there a better option? What are the drawbacks of doing it this way besides having to write more code?

Reason for needing this:

I am writing a code to analyze data coming from instrumentation. The module which connects to the instrumentation needs to be able to broadcast data to other modules for them to analyze. They, in turn, need to broadcast their analyzed data to output modules.

At first glance pub-sub with ZeroMQ seemed perfect for the job, but messages get dropped if any subscriber slows down and hits the high watermark. In the case of this system, it is not acceptable for messages to be dropped at only a fraction of the modules because of event continuity. All the modules need to analyze an event for the output to be meaningful. However, if no modules received the messages for an event, that would be fine. For this reason, it would be okay to block the publisher (the instrumentation module) if one of the analysis modules hit the high watermark.

I suppose another alternative is to deal with missed messages after the fact, but that just wastes processing time on events that would be discarded later.

EDIT:
I guess thinking about this further, I currently expect a message sent = message delivered because I'm using inproc and communicating between threads. However, if I were to send messages over TCP there is a chance that the message could be lost even if ZeroMQ does not drop it on purpose. Does this mean I probably need to deal with dropped messages even if  I use a blocking send? Are there any guarantees about message delivery with inproc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, I think there's no way of providing a guarantee for pub/sub on its own with 0MQ. If you really need completely reliable messaging, you're going to have to roll your own.

Networks are inherently unreliable, which is why TCP does so much handshaking just to get packets across.

As ever, it's a balance between latency and throughput. If you're prepared to sacrifice throughput, you can do message handshaking yourself - perhaps using REQ/REP - and handle the broadcasting yourself.

The 0MQ guide has some ideas on how to go about at least part of what you want [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#toc119).

Answer (score 5):

I agree with SteveL. If you truly need 100% reliability (or close to it), ZeroMq is probably not your solution. You're better off going with commercial messaging products where guaranteed message delivery and persistence are addressed, otherwise, you'll be coding reliability features in ZeroMq and likely pull your hair out in the process. Would you implement your own app server if you required ACID compliance between your application and database? Unless you want to implement your own transaction manager, you'd buy WebLogic, WebSphere, or JBoss to do it for you.

> Does this mean I probably need to deal with dropped messages even if I
>   use a blocking send?

I'd stay away from explicitly blocking *anything*, it's too brittle. A synchronous sender could hang indefinitely if something goes wrong on the consumption side. You could address this using polling and timeouts, but again, it's brittle and messy code; stick with asynchronous.

> Are there any guarantees about message delivery with inproc?

Well, one thing is guaranteed; you're not dealing with physical sockets, so any network issues are eliminated.

Answer (score 3):

This question comes up on search engines, so I just wanted to update.

You can stop ZeroMQ from dropping messages when using PUB sockets. You can set the [ZMQ_XPUB_NODROP option](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-setsockopt), which will instead raise an error when the send buffer is full.

With that information, you could create something like a dead letter queue, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891682/detect-dropped-messages-in-zeromq-queues), and keep trying to resend with sleeps in between.

Efficiently handling this problem may not be possible currently, as there does not appear to be a way to be notified when the send buffer in ZeroMQ is no longer full, which means timed sleeps / polling may be the only way to find out if the send queue has room again so the messages can be published.